# Does garbage collection lead to bad software design?

Tags: garbage-collection

I have heard that garbage collection leads to bad software design. Is that true?  It is true that we don't care about the lifetime of objects in garbage collected languages, but does that have an effect in program design?

Comment: I've never heard that. I have experienced that GC leads to better software design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an object asks other objects to do something on its behalf until further notice, the object's owner should notify it when its services are not required.  Having code abandon such objects without notifying them that their services won't be required anymore would be bad design, but that would be just as true in a garbage-collected framework as in a non-GC framework.

Garbage-collected frameworks, used properly, offer two advantages:

1. In many cases, objects are created for the purpose of encapsulating values therein, and references to the objects are passed around as proxies for that data.  Code receiving such references shouldn't care about whether other references exist to those same objects or whether it holds the last surviving references.  As long as someone holds a reference to an object, the data should be kept.  Once nobody needs the data anymore, it should cease to exist, but nobody should particularly notice.
2. In non-GC frameworks, an attempt to use a disposed object will usually generate Undefined Behavior that cannot be reliably trapped (and may allow code to violate security policies).  In many GC frameworks, it's possible to ensure that attempts to use disposed resources will be trapped deterministically and cannot undermine security.

In some cases, garbage-collection will allow a programmer to "get away with" designs that are sloppier than would be tolerable in a non-GC system.  A GC-based framework will also, however, allow the use of many good programming patterns which would could not be implemented as efficiently in a non-GC system.  For example, if a program uses multiple worker threads to find the optimal solution for a problem, and has a UI thread which periodically wants to show the best solution found so far, the UI thread would want to know that when it asks for a status update it will get *a* solution that has been found, but won't want to burden the worker threads with the synchronization necessary to ensure that it has the absolute-latest solution.

In a non-GC system, thread synchronization would be unavoidable, since the UI thread and worker thread would have to coordinate who was going to delete a status object that becomes obsolete while it's being shown.  In a GC-based system, however, the GC would be able to tell whether a UI thread was able to grab a reference to a status object before it got replaced, and thus resolve whether the object needed to be kept alive long enough for the UI thread to display it.  The GC would sometimes have to force thread synchronization to find all reachable references, but occasional synchronization for the GC may pose less of a performance drain better than the frequent thread synchronization required in a non-GC system.

Comment: A non GC language could trap Use-After-Dispose just as easily. But they usually don't Dispose things, they `delete` them.

Comment: @HenkHolterman: A tracing-GC language can maintain an absolute invariant that as long as there is any conceivable code path via which a reference to an object might be reachable, the reference will never be interpreted as identifying anything else.  The most practical I can think of offering such a guarantee without a tracing GC would be to have references contain handles rather than direct pointers, and have every reference also contain a serial number such that even if a handle gets recycled is serial number wouldn't match that of any existing references to it.  I can't think of any...

Comment: ...alternative approach with less overhead, but having to maintain serial number with every reference and check it on every access seems rather expensive compared with using a tracing GC.